# Is it better to build three separate dialog boxes for separate functionality (add/edit/delete item) or one that can do all three?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I have made a custom `DialogBox` that accepts a key in the constructor then sets itself up based on the key. 
It functions as a box for adding editing or deleting objects depending on which key is passed in the constructor.
For example, if the ADD key is passed then there are `TextBoxes` to allow editing of parameters for submission. If the EDIT key is passed then some of those `TextBoxes` are replaced with `Labels`, and some of the text and functionality of the `Buttons` are modified.
Is this bad design practice?
Is it better to have three separate `DialogBoxes` for each function?

Comment: How do you define "better"? Better usability? Better maintainability? Fewer lines of code? Fewer branches?

Comment: Usability and maintainability mostly. Following good coding practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question in combination with the tags used is a bit ambiguous. I am not quite sure if you are talking about UI design, or object-oriented design. I will, therefore, try to provide answers to both.

**UI Design**

When it comes to UI design, first read and try to understand [the eight golden rules of UI](https://faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/360/f04/sessions/schneidermanGoldenRules.html). There are some variations to these out there, but you will get the gist. The first rule says **Strive for consistency**. With the design you described, it does just that: the Add and Update controls resemble each other. A familiar screen will appear and users should have no trouble finding their way around on that particular form.
Furthermore, when you are dealing with data that can be visualized as a table, you always need to provide two views:

1. multi-record view, as a data grid, where you can observe multiple records at the same time, possibly with lower level of details
2. single record view, which serves as a detailed view for a single record, and can be used for adding or updating records

The dialog box you described sounds like it can be used for the latter purpose.

**Edit: Expanding on the answer based on the first comment below**

From the UI perspective, it sounds just fine to me. Also, from the reusability perspective. You already wrote some code once. To write a new dialog box that would resemble the previous one a lot just for another operation would result in a lot of duplicated code. Duplicated code is a breeding ground for bugs that are result of fixing something in one place, but forgetting to fix it in another. Keep it like this. The more common code the better.

**Object-oriented design**

I truly hope your dialog box does not do all three things you described. Actually, I hope it does none of those. CRUD operations should not be performed by UI components. UI components should only take care of the visual representation of the data and collecting the data from users. Everything else should be performed by other components. By the design you described, you could easily have [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) implemented. You would simply instantiate an appropriate command based on the arguments passed through a constructor of the dialog box, and then let the command execute what needs to be executed. Dialog box would just be a wrapper around it. A nice body of the car, if you wish, whereas all the work would be done by the engine in form of an appropriate command class.

I hope this helps.

**Edit: Expanding on the answer based on the first comment below**

Actually, this external API works just fine with [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). All you should do is wrap the calls to that external API in a single class, and then invoke the appropriate calls from the different command classes, which would be instantiated based on the type of your dialog box.
Also, look into [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334578/what-is-dependency-injection). That should help you decouple the UI related code from the data handling code, which should improve code readability and testability.

Comment: I'm using GWT and Java EE. So I have a  `TabPanel` that displays the table data. Then when you select a row and press an add, edit or delete button the `DialogBox` is shown in the correct mode. At the moment the add form contains a `FormPanel` and `UploadPanel`. When the user presses submit the details are passed to a completely different server using the `FormPanel`. At the same time there is an API call to another service to save metadata to a database. Does this sound OK to you? The http request functionality for the `FormPanel` is built in, I didn't think there was an issue using that.

Answer (score 3):

I will often reuse the same dialog windows with minor changes for the creation of a new entity vs editing an existing entity, because the difference is not important enough to merit a difference.  If anything, create the editing version of the dialog and extend it by disabling controls or changing labels where needed in an "add" version of the dialog, for instance, disabling the key field for being modified.

Also in a related note, consider using UUID.randomUUID() to create a unique and hidden key that doesn't change rather than letting the key be an input by the user.  It eliminates the necessity to maintain consistency throughout your program when the key changes (i.e. redefining maps when the key changes).